# Delphi send null string to webservice

Tags: .net, web-services, delphi

I'm using my WebService from Delphi application, but, in my webservice, the parameter's value always get null.

Here is my web service code in .net

[WebMethod]
int ExecSQL(string ASQL)
{ 
}

in delphi I use like this : [Delphi Method for using web service which I have used](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Delphi-Kylix/Creating-a-Web-Service-Client-with-Delphi/)

I don't know what is wrong ? my delphi application or my .net webservice ?

Comment: Are you able to successfully call the web service from SoapUI?

Comment: Yes, I am able but the parameter is null again. I don't know the why I call the service and I debug it the parameter is null.

Comment: If you can't successfully make a call from SoapUI, then your problem is probably with the web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this service unit:

```
InvRegistry.RegisterInvokeOptions(TypeInfo(xxx), ioDocument);
```

Read here:
https://www.bobswart.nl/weblog/Blog.aspx?RootId=5:798